# Select one of each column value based on the maximum value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return a record of each prod_numb and the cost_amt based on the most recent sale_date column.

Basically I need something like this:

```
SELECT prod_numb  
     , cost_amt 
  FROM product_cost 
 WHERE MAX(sale_date)
```

I know this will not run, but its best way to describe it.
Can someone help with this query?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [prod_numb] => 2336
        [cost_amt] => 32.00
        [sale_date] => 2015-01-01
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [prod_numb] => 2336
        [cost_amt] => 32.00
        [sale_date] => 2015-01-02
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [prod_numb] => 2458
        [cost_amt] => 32.00
        [sale_date] => 2015-01-03
    )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a inner join with the subselect grouped  by prod_num for max date

```
select  prod_numb, cost_amt 
FROM product_cost 
inner join (
  select prod_numb, MAX(sale_date) max_date 
  FROM product_cost 
  group by prod_numb
) t on t.prod_numb = product_cost.prod_numb and t.max_date  = product_cost.sale_date
```

Comment: sir you missing as  alias from query MAX(sale_date) as max_date

Comment: @MohitKumar  .. in mysql the 'AS'  in not mandatory ..   .. explain better

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:-

```
SELECT prod_numb, cost_amt 
   FROM product_cost WHERE 
sale_date = (SELECT max(sale_date) FROM product_cost);
```

Comment: This only returns one record with the max date. I need to return each prod_numb and cost_amt based on the max date.

Comment: You're right, now i see that second option don't meet your requirement, but what about first one. It should return every record with max (sale_date)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I figured it out.

```
 SELECT pm.prod_numb, pm.long_desc, pm.price_amt, tp.location_id, tp.adult_child_flg, pc.cost_amt FROM product_master pm INNER JOIN ticket_product tp ON pm.prod_numb = tp.prod_numb LEFT OUTER JOIN product_cost pc ON pc.prod_numb = pm.prod_numb AND pc.sale_date = TODAY WHERE pm.status = 'A'
```